# Reading JSON encoded array with multiple rows

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON array as shown below :

```
[{"id":"1","text":" Hi this is text 1","value":"200"},
 {"id":"2","text":" Hi This is text 2","value":"300"}]
```

Now in jQuery file I have a GET request and I am doing something like below but it's not working.

```
$.get("get.php",{city:selectedCity},function(data){
 if(data)       //  I have tried even [ data!=0 and  data!="" ] .....but will not work 
{
 alert("data received");
}

else alert(" Not received ");

},"json");
```

But strangely the things are not working as intended. Please tell me if i am reading the array wrongly.

Comment: Presumably `get.php` isn't serving up the data as you expect. You'll have to use a debugger like Firebug to confirm this on your end. Incidentally, [`.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) can save you a little code here.

Comment: I have used firebug to see the response . The jquery file status shows NOT MODIfIEd and the PHP file get.php doesnt loads up at all in files listed under NETWORK tab as it should be.  It should be listed ......ryt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALright ! The problem was with variable name which wasn't send correctly to php file . Problem solved . Thanks for the comments guys

Answer (score 0):

for multiple items i do this:

{"items": [{ "id": 1, "name": "test name 1" }, { "id": 2, "name": "test name 2" }] }

then parse like this:

```
$.each(data.items, function () {
    alert(this.name);
});
```

if you're having issues with the json syntax, copy and paste the string you're getting into http://jsonlint.com/ to test.

also, you might want to look into getJSON
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/